# bpf_override_return not working with uretprobes

Tags: c, go, ebpf, bpf, uprobe

I encountered an issue when attempting to utilize `uretprobe` with `bpf_override_return`. I attached `uretprobe` to a Python library function that returns the current real-time. My goal was to modify the time with a different older time, but I encountered the following problem:
The error message received was: cannot create bpf perf link: invalid argument.

The kernel-side code is as follows:

```c
SEC("uretprobe/_PyTime_GetSystemClock")
int _PyTime_GetSystemClock_bpf(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    u64 id = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    u32 pid = id >> 32;

    u32 kZero = 0;
    u32 *appPid = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&app_pid_map, &kZero);
    if (appPid)
    {
        if (pid != *appPid && pid != 1369246)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    u64 time = (PT_REGS_RC(ctx));

    bpf_printk("[_PyTime_GetSystemClock_bpf]Info: called :%lu & time is:%llu", pid, time);
    u64 t = 1706533301399118410; // Some time value to overwrite
    long ret = bpf_override_return(ctx, t);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        bpf_printk("[_PyTime_GetSystemClock_bpf]Error: bpf_override_return failed");
        return 0;
    }
    // Print the process pid
    bpf_printk("[_PyTime_GetSystemClock_bpf]Info: Modified time for pid: %lu & time is:%llu", pid, t);
    return 0;
}
```

In the userspace code:

```golang
binPath := "/usr/bin/python3.10"
symbol := "_PyTime_GetSystemClock"
// Open an ELF binary and read its symbols.
ex, err := link.OpenExecutable(binPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("opening executable: %s", err)
}

// Open a Uretprobe at the exit point of the symbol and attach
// the pre-compiled eBPF program to it.
up, err := ex.Uretprobe(symbol, objs.PyTimeGetSystemClockBpf, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("creating uretprobe: %+v", err)
}
defer up.Close()
```

No issues occur when not using `bpf_override_return`, and the required configuration `CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE=y` is enabled on my machine.

Output of `sudo strace -f -ebpf ./program` is below:

```bash
strace: Process 1535632 attached
strace: Process 1535633 attached
strace: Process 1535634 attached
strace: Process 1535635 attached
strace: Process 1535636 attached
[pid 1535631] bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=4, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, map_name="", map_ifindex=0, btf_fd=0, btf_key_type_id=0, btf_value_type_id=0, btf_vmlinux_value_type_id=0, map_extra=0}, 72) = 3
Ebpf Loader PID: 1535631
strace: Process 1535637 attached
strace: Process 1535638 attached
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=4, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, map_name="feature_test", map_ifindex=0, btf_fd=0, btf_key_type_id=0, btf_value_type_id=0, btf_vmlinux_value_type_id=0, map_extra=0}, 72) = 3
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=4, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, map_name=".test", map_ifindex=0, btf_fd=0, btf_key_type_id=0, btf_value_type_id=0, btf_vmlinux_value_type_id=0, map_extra=0}, 72) = 3
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=41, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = 3
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\f"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=51, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = 3
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\f"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=51, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = 3
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\23"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=54, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
[pid 1535637] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\2\0\0\20\2\0\0#\3\0\0*\2\0\0\1\0\0\f"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=1355, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = 3
[pid 1535635] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535638] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535635] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
strace: Process 1535641 attached
[pid 1535637] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535638] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535638] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535638] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535638] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] --- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1535631, si_uid=0} ---
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE, insn_cnt=6, insns=0x400069de60, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0, fd_array=NULL}, 144) = 7
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE, insn_cnt=102, insns=0x4001132000, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(5, 15, 131), prog_flags=0, prog_name="_PyTime_GetSyst", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=3, func_info_rec_size=8, func_info=0x400001cc80, func_info_cnt=1, line_info_rec_size=16, line_info=0x400000c700, line_info_cnt=13, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0, fd_array=NULL}, 144) = 7
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_BTF_LOAD, {btf="\237\353\1\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0(\0\0\0(\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\10"..., btf_log_buf=NULL, btf_size=88, btf_log_size=0, btf_log_level=0}, 32) = 3
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH, key_size=4, value_size=4, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, map_name="app_pid_map", map_ifindex=0, btf_fd=3, btf_key_type_id=1, btf_value_type_id=1, btf_vmlinux_value_type_id=0, map_extra=0}, 72) = 8
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x40013b05f0, license="MIT", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(5, 15, 131), prog_flags=0, prog_name="probe_bpf_perf_", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0, fd_array=NULL}, 144) = 9
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_LINK_CREATE, {link_create={prog_fd=9, target_fd=0, attach_type=BPF_PERF_EVENT, flags=0}}, 64) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 1535634] bpf(BPF_LINK_CREATE, {link_create={prog_fd=7, target_fd=3, attach_type=BPF_PERF_EVENT, flags=0}}, 64) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
2024/01/30 11:37:07 creating uretprobe: cannot create bpf perf link: invalid argument
[pid 1535636] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535633] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535637] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535634] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535641] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535638] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535632] +++ exited with 1 +++
[pid 1535635] +++ exited with 1 +++
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: I can't see the relation between BPF perf links and `bpf_override_return`. This is weird. Could you attach the output of `strace -f -ebpf program`? It may help understand why it's trying to create a BPF perf link.

Comment: Also, when you say it works without `bpf_override_return`, you really mean just the `bpf_override_return` call is commented and everything else is exactly the same (including the `bpf_printk` statements)?

Comment: @pchaigno I've attached the required logs. And yes if comment out from 
u64 t = 1706533301399118410;  to last print statement,
then it works.

Comment: I've tested it on a basic Go application with only one function that I probed, and unfortunately, I encountered the same error in that scenario as well.